# Kendo UI MVC Grid ViewModel Binding NullReference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-binding, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm working with the Kendo UI Grid and attempting to bind to a `List<T>` in my View Model. Unfortunately, I'm continually receiving a `NullReferenceException` on `Model.DeliveredLoads`. I have a breakpoint set in my controller, and when debugging, the controller method is not being loaded, nor is the breakpoint getting hit.

It appears as though the grid is trying to bind prior to the data being available in the View Model, hence the error.

Here's what I have in my ViewModel.cs file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SmartAppData;
using SmartAppData.Services;

namespace SmartAppV1.Models
{
    public class DispatchBoardViewModel
    {
        public List<OrdHeader> OrderHeaders
        {
            get
            {
                var service = new OrderService();
                var orders = service.GetOrders();
                return (List<OrdHeader>)orders;
            }
        }
        public OrderTmsStatus OrderTmsStatus => new OrderTmsStatus();

        private string _defaultOrderTmsStatus;
        public string DefaultOrderTmsStatus
        {
            get { return OrderTmsStatus.Planned.ToString(); }
            set { _defaultOrderTmsStatus = value; }
        }

        public List<Load> DeliveredLoads { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My controller action:

```
public ActionResult DispatchBoard()
{
    var service = new OrderService();
    var loadService = new LoadService();

    var viewModel = new DispatchBoardViewModel();
    viewModel.DefaultOrderTmsStatus = OrderTmsStatus.New.ToString();

    // Get list of delivered loads (grid #4)
    viewModel.DeliveredLoads = loadService.GetLoadsByBookedByIdByTmsStatus(110, LoadTmsStatus.Delivered.ToString());

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And, finally, my view:

```
@model SmartAppV1.Models.DispatchBoardViewModel

<div class="section group">
    <div id="col4" class="col span_1_of_4 fullContainerHeight">
        <div class="commandBar">
            <i class="fa fa-expand fa-inverse floatRight clickPointer" onclick="expandColumn(this);"></i>
        </div>
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.DeliveredLoads)
            .Name("Grid_4_of_4")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.LoadId).Title("Load Id");
            })
            .Pageable()
            )
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

Since I'm putting the data into the View Model (and not anticipating a large amount of data - generally no more than 30 rows) I don't see why there would be any need for a Json method to load/page/sort the data.

I just don't understand why the grid seems to be trying to bind before the Model is fully hydrated.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Ric

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that. While initializing the grid, you are saying the grid will be using the model 'Model.DeliveredLoads'. It is just for model binding. It will not have data at that time. You have to call read method for the grid. Then it means you will be reading the data from read method  from controller.

```
@model SmartAppV1.Models.DispatchBoardViewModel

<div class="section group">
<div id="col4" class="col span_1_of_4 fullContainerHeight">
    <div class="commandBar">
        <i class="fa fa-expand fa-inverse floatRight clickPointer" onclick="expandColumn(this);"></i>
    </div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.DeliveredLoads)
        .Name("Grid_4_of_4")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.LoadId).Title("Load Id");
        })
        .Pageable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")))
        )

</div>
```